# Slide a div down upon clicking a row from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What I'm trying to achieve is that a div should be slide down just below the row upon clicking the row. I does works for the first time when the data gets generated via AJAX. but it does not works when I'm generating data after the first time, though the event is triggered but `$('.test').slideUp(0) $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));`  does not works after the first time. Nor any error is popped .

I want that a div should slide down just below the row which is clicked. It does works but only for the 1st time when I generate the data via Ajax. Upon generating the table after the 1st time, the div does not slides down.

For eg:- When I click an `li` item a table will appear. Upon clicking on any of the rows, a div will appear saying `You slide down a row with content xyz`. but when I click an item again from the list, and then the row from the corresponding table, the div doesn't shows up.

See http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/5/

Comment: When you're doing `$(this).append(($('.test'))` you're removing it from the DOM and appending to to the `tr` in question. But when you click on the `li` you're loading new content to the table and thus `$('.test')` is now no longer available.

Comment: So, what should I do to solve this?

Comment: You'll need to put it back to the DOM - check my answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing `$(this).append(($('.test'))` you're removing it from the DOM and appending to to the `tr` that is being clicked. But when you click on the li you're loading new content to the table and thus `$('.test')` is now no longer available.

To solve this, one easy fix is to append the `.test` div back to the body element when you click on the `li`:

`$('body').append($('.test').slideUp(0));`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/9/

Comment: Simple and yet powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
  <div class="test">You slide down a row with content xyz</div>
```

is disappearing from the dom after the ajax request.

You can try

```
 $('#list').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $("body").append("<div class='test'>You slide down a row with content xyz</div>");
```

and remove the `div` from html

Comment: I've tried this. But this keeps appending the div on multiple clicking, which is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly place that `div` by using the [outer-height](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) of the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(this).append(($('.test')).toggle('slow'));
```

use this

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/8/)

Comment: but upon multiple clicking a row , why that div is getting appended again and again. Moreover when I click other rows, and that div does not slides up

Comment: when u click multiple times , the element is still there to find, not replaced , so it can add it

Comment: but sir, I dont want that, I want if I click the same row again, it should toggle. and If I click other rows, that div should slide up for the previous row and slide down for the current row being clicked. Thanks

Comment: Its not working. Its the same issue that I'm facing. It does works but only for the 1st time when I generate the data via Ajax. Upon generating the table after the 1st time, the div does not slides down.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below scripts will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('YOUR_ROW_ID/ELEMENT_NAME').click(function(){
          $('.test').append().html("<div>Your Content over here....</div>").toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I also tried this. But I want the div should be placed just under the current row being clicked, not after the table.

Answer (score 0):

When you load new content in from your ajax call, you are more than likely replacing the entire table. This will loose any bound associations with events you have.

A solution is to bind the click event to a lower level unchanging element and allow it to bubble up to the selector you want.

```
$('body').on('click', 'table#table_contents tr', function(event) {
     // Your click event code here
});
```

This will allow you to replace the table without unbinding any attached events to removed DOM elements.

**Additional from comments**
The real problem is the selection of the row to slide down. As this changes when a new table is loaded there needs to be a way to select that content.

You mention in comments that this row will have an id equal to the `<li>` that was clicked to open the table. You shouldn't ever have two dom elements on the page with the same ID. Instead I have formatted the slide down like this:

```
<div class="test" data-id="1">You slide down a row with content xyz</div>
```

The JS also contains a local scoped variable to the document ready function `clickedId` that contains the last clicked `<li>`'s id.

```
var clickedId;

$('#list').on('click', 'li', function(){
    clickedId = parseInt(this.id, 10);

    var cols = [[0,4],[5,9],[10,15],[15,19],[25,29]],
        table_content = getContent(cols[clickedId - 1]);

    $("#table_content").html(table_content);
});
```

Now in the table event handler we use the `clickedId` variable to find the `data-id` attribute of the row to show.

```
$('body').on('click', 'table#table_content tr', function () {
    var row = $('[data-id="' + clickedId + '"]');

    row.slideUp(0);
    $(this).append(row);
    row.slideDown(200);
});
```

Just for convenience I also turned the long `if else` code sequence into a function

```
function getContent(iCols)
{
    var table_content = '';

    for( var i = 0; i <4;i++){
        table_content += "<tr>";
        for(var j = iCols[0];j<iCols[1];j++) {
            table_content +="<td>"+j+"</td>"
        }
        table_content += "</tr>";
    }

    return table_content;
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle example for you](http://jsfiddle.net/8BkbL/2/)

Comment: Not working. Its the same issue that I'm facing. See this line. `I want that a div should slide down just below the row which is clicked. It does works but only for the 1st time when I generate the data via Ajax. Upon generating the table after the 1st time, the div does not slides down`

Comment: Then the `.test` div must be being removed as well when you replace the table. I just ran this through a quick test before I posted it. Does this div that slides down change per request?

Comment: Yes. There is a different div for each item list.

Comment: And this div has the same class `.test`?

Comment: No. This was just a demo. There are different divs for each item list with different ids and class. Infact class wont be provided, since the content is different for each div.

Comment: In that case then the solution lies in how you select the div in the click event. If there is no class or id, does it have a parent that it will always be inside? Maybe you could add the ajax success to the question.

Comment: Its like this. For Item 1 - `<div id = '1'>abc</div>`. For Item 2 - `<div id = '2'>def</div>`. For Item 3 - `<div id = '3'>aghi</div>` and so on.

Comment: Should I keep cloning the multiple divs again again. In this demo example there are only 5 divs for 5 list items. What if I've 20divs for each 20 items.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with a solution that will work when you swap out the slide down div. It will require a little bit of a re-work as you should never have elements with the same ID attribute in the DOM at any one time.